# Error ::Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net

trying to hide a panel of Master Page in my content page using the following code

```
 Panel p = this.Master.FindControl("panel1") as Panel;  
 p.Visible = false; //Error is showing on this line
```

Why this error ?

Comment: The problem is probably elsewhere. Might you have unbalanced {} characters?

Comment: it WAS the braces..thanks ! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you've got the code like this:

```
class MyPage : Page
{
    Panel p = this.Master.FindControl("panel1") as Panel;  
    p.Visible = false;
}
```

You can't just put code in the class like that - everything other than declarations (e.g. fields) needs to be in a method:

```
class MyPage : Page
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel p = this.Master.FindControl("panel1") as Panel;  
        p.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I go with Jon's answer. Otherwise this error message is not possible. Check the placement of your code and check the placement and existence of the braces ({})

Comment: @user289524: As Mario says, that's what the error message is about. I suggest you keep a backup of your code, and then remove everything extraneous until you've got nothing but the class declaration and enough of Page_Load to show the error. I'm sure when you start removing bits, you'll find the error.