# Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, class, struct

I have this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ComputerGraphicsExercises
{
    class Adamak
    {
        public int BodyX1;
        public int BodyX2;
        public int HeadX;
        public int LeftArmX1;
        public int LeftArmX2;
        public int RightArmX1;
        public int RightArmX2;
        public int LeftLegX1;
        public int LeftLegX2;
        public int RightLegX1;
        public int RightLegX2;
        public int LeftEyeX;
        public int RightEyeX;
        public int PupilOfLeftEyeX;
        public int PupilOfRightEyeX;
        public int NoseX;
        public int LipsX;
        public int HairX;
        public int LeftEarX;
        public int RightEarX;

        public int BodyY1;
        public int BodyY2;
        public int HeadY;
        public int LeftArmY1;
        public int LeftArmY2;
        public int RightArmY1;
        public int RightArmY2;
        public int LeftLegY1;
        public int LeftLegY2;
        public int RightLegY1;
        public int RightLegY2;
        public int LeftEyeY;
        public int RightEyeY;
        public int PupilOfLeftEyeY;
        public int PupilOfRightEyeY;
        public int NoseY;
        public int LipsY;
        public int HairY;
        public int LeftEarY;
        public int RightEarY;
    }
}
```

And I declared a variable like this:

```
namespace ComputerGraphicsExercises
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        Adamak iMan2 = new Adamak();
    }
}
```

Now I want to change the value of the:

```
iMan2.BodyX1 = 50;
```

but I get this error:

> Error 1   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   C:\vc\ComputerGraphicsExercises\ComputerGraphicsExercises\Main.cs   17  22  ComputerGraphicsExercises

What is my mistake?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766660/need-help-with-this-error-invalid-token-in-class-struct-or-interface-mem

Comment: possibly this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a value to a field of the instance of the class outside any constructor or method. That is why

Comment: Thanks, but I need this variable to be global, where else do you recommend me to create the instance. This is a Windows Form project.

Comment: A variable must be defined in a method, constructor or class. You can for example create a class that has this variable as a static property and then it will be accessible in a global scope. Just keep in mind that having global variables is not a very good practice, especially for larger code bases.